# Whenever I try to do sudo apt-get install I get stuck in logging in

Tags: apt

Whenever I try to install packages or update using apt-get, I get stuck at 0%[logging in].

```
Err ftp://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main libcurl3 amd64 7.38.0-3ubuntu2.3
Connection timeout
Err ftp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main libcurl3 amd64 7.38.0-3ubuntu2.3
Connection timeout
Err ftp://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main curl amd64 7.38.0-3ubuntu2.3
Connection timeout
Err ftp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main curl amd64 7.38.0-3ubuntu2.3
Connection timeout
E: Failed to fetch ftp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl3_7.38.0-3ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  
Connection timeout
E: Failed to fetch ftp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.38.0-3ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb  
Connection timeout
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Your internet connection is working well?

Comment: Yes, I am posting this question with the same Internet connection

Comment: Can you access any FTP server with your internet connection?

Comment: I'm sorry, but how do I check that?

Comment: See if you get proper respond from this command: `ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: I can open `ftp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/` in a browser. Can you?

Comment: @katutxakurra I'm able to open it.

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha I am getting 100% packet loss